# Filter org-file using tags

Tags: org-mode, tags, filtering

I've this org-file:

```
* Headline a                                                           :tag1:
Text for my Headline a

* Headline b                                                           :tag2:
Text for my Headline b

* Headline c                                                           :tag1:
Text for my Headline c

* Headline d                                                           :tag4:
Text for my Headline d
```

What is the command to get the following output (show only headline with tag1)?

```
* Headline a                                                           :tag1:
Text for my Headline a

* Headline c                                                           :tag1:
Text for my Headline c
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `org-sparse-tree` (do `C-h f org-sparse-tree` for details) which is bound (for me) to `C-c /`.

Thus `C-c / m tag1` will only show headlines matching (that is the force of the `m`) `tag1`.

Comment: Using `org-sparse-tree`  you get a buffer in which the headlines matching `tag1` are highlighted but the headlines with different tags are not deleted

Comment: I've noticed that the `org-sparse-tree` command only works with level 2+ but not with level 1 headlines. The simplest solution I've found (and without writing elisp code) is to demote all headlines 1 and put them under a headline at level 1. At this point the `org-spase-tree` command hide no matching headlines but this trick still doesn't work if you want to SAVE a buffer containing ONLY the searched and displayed headlines

Comment: I think you can save a buffer with the sparse tree using the org export mechanism (export to org...).

Comment: I tried with `C-c C-e C-v` but there is no possibility to export "from org to org" (only "from org to HTML, PDF, etc."). It seems so strange and frustrating to me that there isn't an easy way to "extract" sub-trees of headlines...

Comment: `C-c C-e C-v O` gets me to an "export to org" menu.  Have you required `ox`?

Comment: Even if I request `ox` I still don't have the possibility to export from org to org. Do you have anything else in your setup besides `(require 'ox)` to have `org` to `org` export option?

Comment: Not that I can see.